# XamarinForms how to make two input fields in a popup element

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please tell me how to make it possible to add another message to DisplayPromptAsync? that is, one more line to enter, so that there are two of them. Maybe somehow override the method?

[image]

Comment: DisplayPrompt only supports a single input.  For multiple input you can try using Rg Plugins or another similar library

Comment: @Jason Yes, thanks. Your advice has been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with dependency service , check the sample for iOS

#### Define a interface

```
public interface IAlert
{
    //return the input string
    Task<string> showSingle(string title, string message);
    //return the two input strings
    Task<string[]> showMutiple(string title,string message);
}
```

#### Implement in platform project

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Alert))]
namespace ColeForms.iOS
{
    public class Alert : IAlert
    {     
        public Task<string> showSingle(string title, string message)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

            string result = "";

            UIAlertController c = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            c.AddTextField((t) => {});

            UIAlertAction action = UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (a) => {
                c.DismissModalViewController(true);
                result = c.TextFields[0].Text;
                tcs.SetResult(result);
            });
            c.AddAction(action);

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(c, true, null);

            return tcs.Task;
        }

        public Task<string[]> showMutiple(string title, string message)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string[]>();

            string[] result = new string[2];

            UIAlertController c = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            c.AddTextField((t) => {});
            c.AddTextField((t) => {});

            UIAlertAction action = UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (a) => {
                c.DismissModalViewController(true);

                result[0] = c.TextFields[0].Text;
                result[1] = c.TextFields[1].Text;
                tcs.SetResult(result);
            });
            c.AddAction(action);

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(c, true, null);

            return tcs.Task;
        }

    }
}
```

#### Invoke in Forms

```
var result = await DependencyService.Get<IAlert>().showSingle("title","msg");
```

[image]